# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException keeps appearing while trying to find most occuring word in file

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am currently building a program which reads a file and prints the most occurring words and how many times each word appears like so:

```
package WordLookUp;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class WordLookUp {

    private String[] mostWords;
    private Scanner reader;
    private String line;
    private FileReader fr;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private List<String> original;
    private String token = " ";


    public WordLookUp(String file) throws Exception {
        this.reader = new Scanner(new File(file));
        this.original = new ArrayList<String>();



        while (this.reader.hasNext()) { //reads file and stores it in string
            this.token = this.reader.next();
            this.original.add(token); //adds it to my arrayList
        }


    }

    public void findMostOccurringWords() {
        List<String> mostOccur = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int counter = 0;


        this.mostWords = this.token.split(" "); //storing read lines in mostWords arrayList

        try {

        for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++) {
            if (this.original.equals(this.mostWords[i])) { 
                counter++; //increase counter
                mostOccur.add(this.mostWords[i]);
                count.add(counter);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mostOccur.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Word: " + mostOccur.get(i) + " count: " + count.get(i));
        }

        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae) {
            System.out.println("Illegal index");
        }
    }






}


package WordLookUp;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        WordLookUp wL = new WordLookUp("tiny1.txt");

        wL.findMostOccurringWords();



    }

}
```

So when I keep running my file, it throws the exception I gave it: "Illegal index". I think it is my `findMostOccuringWords` method. To me the logic feels correct, but I don't know why it is throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I tried playing with the for loops and tried to go from `int i = 0 to i < mostOccur.size() - 1` but that is not working either. Is my logic wrong ? I am not allowed to use a `hashmap` and our professor gave us a hint that we can do this assignment easily with arrays and `ArrayLists` (no other built in functions, but regexes is highly recommended for use as well for the rest of the assignment). I put a private `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` up there as I am trying to see if they would work better or not. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I'm not sure that suggesting to use lists is good advice here.  Instead, consider using a map of some kind, with the key being the word, and the value being the number of occurrences.  Then, you can easily iterate all known words and obtain their counts.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I wish I could use an Hashmap but this for my data structures class in university and our professor is not allowing it! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use the following codes? I think your current algorithm is wrong.

```
public class WordLookUp {
private List<String> original;
private List<String> mostOccur = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();


public WordLookUp(String file) throws Exception {
    try(Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(file));){
        this.original = new ArrayList<String>();
        String token = " ";
        while (reader.hasNext()) { //reads file and stores it in string
            token = reader.next();
            this.original.add(token); //adds it to my arrayList
            findMostOccurringWords(token);
        }
    }
}

public void findMostOccurringWords(String token) {
    int counter = 0;
    String[] mostWords = token.split(" "); //storing read lines in mostWords arrayList
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < mostWords.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.original.size(); j++) {
                if (original.get(j).equals(mostWords[i])) {
                    counter++; //increase counter
                }
            }
            if (mostOccur.contains(mostWords[i])) {
                count.set(mostOccur.indexOf(mostWords[i]),counter);
            }else {
                mostOccur.add(mostWords[i]);
                count.add(counter);
            }
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae) {
        System.out.println("Illegal index");
    }
}

public void count() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mostOccur.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Word: " + mostOccur.get(i) + " count: " + count.get(i));
    }
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WordLookUp wL = new WordLookUp("F:\\gc.log");

    wL.count();

}
```

}

Comment: You are awesome and it works sir! Thank you! I will write my own version of it!

Comment: Could please mark this answer is correct if it has solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here in this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mostOccur.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println("Word: " + mostOccur.get(i) + " count: " + count.get(i));
}
```

You check to make sure that `i` is within bounds for `mostOccur` but not `count`. I would add a condition to check to make sure it is in bounds. Such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mostOccur.size() && i < count.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println("Word: " + mostOccur.get(i) + " count: " + count.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception, but now my program is not outputting anything and debugging is not showing anything wrong with it. Any ideas on what's the problem here ?

Comment: @SaturnsBelt Try printing out the contents of `mostWords`. (Hint look at the line `this.mostWords = this.token.split(" ");`. What is `token`?)